# How to copy the directory from one place to another using C language?

Tags: c, linux, directory, copy

I have searched online but didn't a solution. I want to copy the directories/folders from one place to another using C language. Although it could be possible using `cp` in command line but I want to implement that in C language.

Comment: if you can use `system` function, its pretty easy as command

Comment: So there are two plus one problems to solve: 1.1 How to copy a file? 1.2 How to travers a directory tree? 2. How to use the solution to 1.1 on each entry found in 1.2 (if not a directory)?

Comment: @IrAM: That exclicilty not what the OP wants: "* ... could be possible using `cp` ... but I want to implement that in C language.*"

Comment: @IrAM How to copy that?

Comment: @alk How to copy that?

Comment: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cp.c

Comment: @yano I didn't understand what the code is doing. Will you please guide me in a short way?

Comment: To copy a file, open the source file, create the target file, enter a loop reading a byte from the source and writing it to the destination until the source indicated end-of-file, then finally close both files.

Comment: Hello @InotifyLine I'm not totally sure if you need help on your "cp" implementation based on C but as far as I can see a perfect guide/idea how to do it you can find it from the link provided above (@yano post) and over here from the busybox cp.c  --> https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/coreutils/cp.c?h=1_32_stable

Comment: Guys, keep it simple! ;)

Comment: @alk I am not trying to copy a file. I am trying to copy a `folder/directory.`

Comment: @InotifyLine Please [edit] your question to add clarification. If you want to copy the directory structure without the files, then make this clear in your question. Show an example what files and directories exist and what should be the result. I think you cannot use `cp` to copy directories without copying the files.

Answer (score 0):

To copy a folder, including all files and subfolders inside, you need to iterate over the content of the folder, and for each "entry" check if it's a file or folder

- if the entry is a file then you can open it as binary and write all the content to a new file in the output path.
- if the entry is a folder then you need to create the directory in the output path.

To iterate over the content of the folder you can use `readdir` from `dirent.h`, to check if an entry is a folder or file `lstat` and `S_ISDIR` from `sys/stat.h`, and to create folder `mkdir` from `sys/stat.h`.

Answer (score 0):

This needs some polishing (it ought to handle a full path for a target dir, should think about edge cases, etc.), but this is a reasonable start:

```
/* Recursively duplicate a directory tree */                                       
#include <dirent.h>                                                                
#include <err.h>                                                                   
#include <errno.h>                                                                 
#include <limits.h>                                                                
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
#include <string.h>                                                                
#include <sys/stat.h>                                                              
#include <unistd.h>                                                                
                                                                                   
static DIR * xopendir(const char *);                                               
static void xclosedir(DIR *, const char *);                                        
static void xstat(const char *, struct stat *);                                    
static void xrealpath(const char *s, char *resolved);                              
static void pathcat(char *p, char *n);                                             
                                                                                   
struct dir { DIR *d; char *path, *end; };                                          
                                                                                   
static void                                                                        
build_dir(char *spath, char *dpath, char *name, mode_t mod)                        
{                                                                                  
        struct dirent *f;                                                          
        struct dir src;                                                            
        struct dir dst;                                                            
                                                                                   
        src.end = strchr(spath, '\0');                                             
        dst.end = strchr(dpath, '\0');                                             
                                                                                   
        pathcat(dpath, name);                                                      
        if( mkdir(dpath, mod) == -1 && errno != EEXIST ){                          
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", name);                                     
        }                                                                          
                                                                                   
        if( getenv("V") ){                                                         
                printf("%s -> %s\n", spath, dpath);                                
        }                                                                          
        src.d = xopendir(src.path = spath);                                        
                                                                                   
        while( (f = readdir(src.d)) != NULL ) {                                    
                if( !strcmp(f->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(f->d_name, "..") ){         
                        continue;                                                  
                }                                                                  
                if( f->d_type == DT_DIR ){                                         
                        struct stat b;                                             
                        pathcat(spath, f->d_name);                                 
                        xstat(spath, &b);                                          
                        build_dir(spath, dpath, f->d_name, b.st_mode);             
                        *src.end = '\0';                                           
                }                                                                  
        }                                                                          
        *src.end = '\0';                                                           
        *dst.end = '\0';                                                           
        xclosedir(src.d, spath);                                                   
} 
int                                                                                
main(int argc, char **argv)                                                        
{                                                                                  
        if( argc < 2 ){                                                            
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "src directory missing");                       
        }                                                                          
        if( argc < 3 ){                                                            
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "target directory missing");                    
        }                                                                          
        char spath[PATH_MAX];                                                      
        char dpath[PATH_MAX];                                                      
        xrealpath(argv[1], spath);                                                 
                                                                                   
        for( argv += 2; *argv; argv++ ){                                           
                char *name = *argv;                                                
                if( *name == '/' ){                                                
                        dpath[0] = '\0';                                           
                } else {                                                           
                        getcwd(dpath, sizeof dpath);                               
                }                                                                  
                build_dir(spath, dpath, name, 0777);                               
        }                                                                          
        return 0;                                                                  
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
static void                                                                        
xrealpath(const char *s, char *resolved)                                           
{                                                                                  
        if( realpath(s, resolved) == NULL ){                                       
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", s);                                        
        }                                                                          
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
static DIR *                                                                       
xopendir(const char *path)                                                         
{                                                                                  
        DIR *d = opendir(path);                                                    
        if( d == NULL ) {                                                          
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", path);                                     
        }                                                                          
        return d;                                                                  
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
static void                                                                        
xstat(const char *path, struct stat *buf)                                          
{                                                                                  
        if( stat(path, buf) ){                                                     
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "stat %s", path);                                
        }                                                                          
} 
static void                                                                        
xclosedir(DIR *d, const char *path)                                                
{                                                                                  
        if( closedir(d) ) {                                                        
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", path);                                     
        }                                                                          
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
static void                                                                        
pathcat(char *p, char *n)                                                          
{                                                                                  
        if( snprintf(p, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", p, n) > PATH_MAX - 1 ){                 
                errx(1, "path too long");                                          
        }                                                                          
}
```